# How to find a list of distinct dataset from a particular value in Scala?

Tags: list, scala, distinct

There is one case class: "companyDetails"

```
case class companydetails(id: Int, name: String, overview: Int)
```

List of company details looks like something like this:

```
val listOFData:List[companyDetails]={
(1,"google",95),
(2,"Accenture",78),
(3,"google",90),
(4,"facebook",78),
(5,"City", 89)}
```

So I want a list of company details distinct by company name irrespective of the other parameters.

So my expected output should be:

```
{(1,"google",95),(2,"Accenture",78),(4,"facebook",78),(5,"City", 89)}
```

Please help me solve this problem in Scala. Thank you in advance.

Comment: What have you tried? In particular, have you looked at `distinctBy` which appears to do exactly what you want.

Comment: @Tim, I have tried distinctBy, But it is not working. It throws error:    Required: Function1( companyDetails, NotInterredB) , found: List[String]

Answer (score 1):

Use [Scaladoc](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.13.3/index.html), which lists a lot of useful functions, like [`distinctBy`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.13.3/scala/collection/immutable/List.html#distinctBy%5BB%5D(f:A=%3EB):C):

> `def distinctBy[B](f: (A) => B): List[A]`
> Selects all the elements of this immutable sequence ignoring the duplicates as determined by == after applying the transforming function f.

```scala
case class companyDetails(id: Int, name: String, overview: Int)

val listOFData: List[companyDetails] = List(
    (1, "google", 95),
    (2, "Accenture", 78),
    (3, "google", 90),
    (4, "facebook", 78),
    (5, "City", 89)
  )
  .map(companyDetails.apply.tupled)

val result = listOFData.distinctBy(_.name) // will contain unique by name elements
```

Comment: I have tried distinctBy, but it shows :--->Required: Function1( companyDetails, NotInterredB) 
And also, ".map(companyDetails.apply.tupled)" --->  apply method is not working: Missing arguments for method apply(Int, String, Int)

Comment: @PriyaksheeMahanta `.map(companyDetails.apply.tupled)` here is just to easier build `List[companyDetails]` . Also the example is fully [working](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/zBAkGZDbSR6Pg1tWqoMY3A). Please add a [mre] cause currently provided code is not compliable.

Comment: @PriyaksheeMahanta Also [here](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/AxIv4qwbT0Oz0ekJZHxqig) working example without `apply.tupled`